# Find diagonal matrix $D$ so that $AD + B$ has specific eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

### Problem

I have the following matrix equation ($A,B,D$ are all square, $D$ is diagonal):

$$
C=AD + B
$$

Assuming $A$ and $B$ are completely known and the eigenvalues ($\lambda_i$) of $C$ are completely known, how can I go about solving for the diagonal matrix $D$ (numerically or otherwise)?

Out of curiosity, to make this more general, if we don't restrict $D$ to be diagonal, can we solve for its eigenvalues given the same information?

**Edit**: To be clear, $C$ is not known, only its eigenvalues are known. I'm essentially trying to solve for $C$ by first solving for $D$.

### What I've Tried

Since I know the eigenvalues of $C$, I can set up a system of equations in terms of the unknown diagonal elements $\gamma_i$ using the following relationship and the known eigenvalues $\lambda_i$:

$$
\det \left( A 
\begin{bmatrix} 
    \gamma_1 & \dots  & 0\\
    \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
    0 & \dots  & \gamma_n 
    \end{bmatrix}
+ B + \lambda_i I \right) = 0
$$

However, this system is non-linear and is cumbersome to set up and solve when the the matrices get large. Does anyone know of a better way?

Comment: If $A$ is invertible then $D=A^{-1}(C-B)$ is a (non-diagonal) solution given some matrix $C$. I'll write a longer answer.

Comment: This may not have been clear in my post, but $C$ is unknown as well. I've edited to make this clearer.

Comment: @MatthewDvorsky: Let $\Lambda$ be the diagonal matrix whose diagonal values are $C$'s eigenvalues.  Then assuming that $C$'s eigenvectors are linearly independent, $D = A^{-1}(\Lambda - B)$.

Comment: @Dan That value of $D$ is usually not diagonal.

Comment: [Full state feedback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_state_feedback)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Thanks for making this connection. This problem does seem to be equivalent to the problem of pole placement in linear feedback systems. I'll have to do some more research.

Comment: @MatthewDvorsky With the constraint that the feedback matrix is diagonal. In any case, one wonders whether the pair $(B,A)$ is controllable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible idea. Let $d$ denote the vector containing the diagonal entries of $D$, so that $D = \operatorname{diag}(d)$. The fact that $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue of $AD + B$ is equivalent to the existence of a vector $x$ of norm $1$ such that $(AD + B - \lambda_i I)x = 0$. What we're looking for, then, is the parameter $d$ such that the following minimum is achieved:
$$
\min_{d,x_1,\dots,x_n} \sum_{i=1}^n\left\|(AD + B - \lambda_i I)x_i\right\|^2 \quad \text{s.t.} \quad \|x_i\|^2 = 1.
$$
It's difficult (I suspect) to minimize over all parameters simultaneously. However, it's easy to solve for the best $x_i$ given a vector $d$ (using $n$ singular value decompositions) and it's easy to solve for the best vector $d$ for a given set of $x_i$ (via traditional least squares).

I suspect that alternating between minimizing over the $x_i$ and minimizing over $d$ will take you towards the desired overall minimum, similarly to how the method of alternating projections works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Alternating between minimizing over $x_i$ and $d$ seems to work well for small matrices (e.g., for $3$x$3$ or smaller). Unfortunately, based on my simulations, it becomes very sensitive to the initial guess of $d$ for anything larger than $3$x$3$ (it gets stuck in local minima).

Comment: @MatthewDvorsky That's too bad. I guess I'm glad it at least it works in some cases, though